# Update changing wrong column in MYSQL Tem table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_horario` (
  `horas_reales` decimal(7,6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sede` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `periodo` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crn` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `materia` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `curso` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estatus` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seccion` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nivel` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesion` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horas_clase` decimal(9,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `horas_totales` decimal(9,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `horas_pago` decimal(9,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `horas_contacto` decimal(9,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `horas_globales` decimal(9,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_inicio` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_fin` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lunes` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `martes` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `miercoles` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jueves` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `viernes` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sabado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_programado` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `k_sede` (`sede`),
  KEY `k_crn` (`crn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I fill the records with a select like this

```
select 
s.ssbsect_camp_code sede
, s.ssbsect_term_code periodo
, s.ssbsect_crn crn
...
,0 horas_reales -- This value is filled later
, m.ssrmeet_begin_time hora_inicio
, m.ssrmeet_end_time hora_fin
FROM a table with a lot of joins and complex conditions
```

Everything is ok.
But in the next step, I fill the calculated column with this

```
 update tmp_horario h
set h.horas_reales = if(
    h.horas_contacto / h.horas_globales * h.horas_pago > h.horas_contacto
    , h.horas_contacto
    , h.horas_contacto / h.horas_globales * h.horas_pago);
```

As you see only column horas_reales is being set but somehow the neighbor column "hora_inicio" gets changed to even though is not being set nor added to the update.

This is a row before and after the update, the value of an unwanted column(next) gets lost

```
horas_reales|hora_inicio | hora_fin
0           |1100        | 1156
to
1           |(empty)     | 1156
```

The problem goes away if I do not do the update (impossible is needed) 
or if I remove the "filler", `0 horas_reales` from de create table (possible I only use it as a placeholder to fill later).

So the question is why is this happening, is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Random debugging tip: try setting all your DECIMAL types to DOUBLE and see what happens.

Comment: @barrycarter Interesting, that solves the problem at hand, the question remains as to why is this happening, is it a bug or a feature?.

Comment: Probably a bug, you should create a minimal example and report. You're trying to save space using varchars, decimal, and tinyint, and I think you're somehow confusing MySQL's with bit/byte boundaries. Somehow, one column is "leaking" into another (wild guess).